# Unable to select Macbook Pro in target disk mode when booting

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro

I have one Macbook Pro 16 2019 which has a broken screen, and another that works perfectly. I am trying to access the one with the broken screen, but cannot do so because it refuses to connect to any of my monitors. As a result, I am attempting to enter it using target disk mode.

I have placed the broken laptop into target disk mode, and when I have the working laptop on, I can connect the two using a thunderbolt cable and see the target disk Macbook in Finder and Disk Utility and Startup Disks.

But when I restart and try to boot into the target disk Macbook by holding down the option key, only my mac and windows (bootcamp) partitions appear. The target disk Macbook is nowhere to be found. Yet when I log in, I can see it in Finder again just as before.

I have enabled "Allow booting from external or removable media" and set "Secure Boot" to "No Security".

I have tried searching, but haven't seen this behavior described anywhere. Is there anything I could try to get target disk mode working?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've never actually tried it - but, both Macs should be the same or similar models & be running the same OS. Also, must have no filevault & no firmware password.